# How to detect double click with cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x, double-click, multiplatform

How do I port this cocos2d-iphone code to cocos2d-x?

```
(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event  {
 NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches]; 
switch ([allTouches count])    {
case 1:  
    {
        UITouch *touch = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
        switch([touch tapCount]) 
        { 
             case 1:
                  // 单击!
                 break;
             case 2:
                //Double tap.
               // 双击! 
                break;
        } 
   break;    
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no function to implement this,we can implement this by test the tick between two clicks.In general,the time interval of double click is between 250ms~300ms.Use this to get the system's current number of milliseconds

```
long millisecondNow()
{
    struct cc_timeval now;
    CCTime::gettimeofdayCocos2d(&now, NULL);
    return (now.tv_sec * 1000 + now.tv_sec / 1000);
}
```

Comment: Is this called anywhere or do we just implement it?

Answer (score 0):

In MyScene.h, declare:

```
int tapCount;
Touch lastTouch;
void singleTap(float deltaTime);
```

Then in MyScene.cpp:

```
bool MyScene::onTouchBegan(Touch* touch, Event* event)
{
    ++tapCount;
    lastTouch = *touch;

    if (tapCount == 1) {
        this->schedule(schedule_selector(MyScene::singleTap), 0.25, 1, 0);
    }
    else {
        this->unschedule(schedule_selector(MyScene::singleTap));
        tapCount = 0;
        printf("\n\ndouble tap\n\n");
    }

    return true;
}


void MyScene::singleTap(float deltaTime)
{
    this->unschedule(schedule_selector(LevelScene::singleTap));
    tapCount = 0;
    printf("\n\nsingle tap\n\n");
}
```

You can then access lastTouch in singleTap or your doubleTap method.  If you don't need lastTouch to be a Touch object, you can use a Vec2 and set the coordinates.  Note that the timer interval (0.25) is more accurate on the device.  There is a lag in the simulator since the interval isn't actually wall-clock time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
void HelloWorld::callback1()
{
    _tapCount = 0;
}
void HelloWorld::menuCloseCallback(Ref* pSender)
{
    _tapCount = _tapCount + 1;
    if (_tapCount == 1)
    {
        DelayTime* delayAction = DelayTime::create(0.3);
        CallFunc*resetAction = CallFunc::create(CC_CALLBACK_0(HelloWorld::callback1, this));
        Sequence *seq = Sequence::create(delayAction, resetAction, NULL);
        this->runAction(seq);
    }
    else{
        log("double tap");
    };

}
```